# Call native code specified at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, native

I'm developing an application that will allow users to call external code from both managed and native .dlls.  The users will be able to specify what library/method/function to call at runtime (it will be stored in a configuration file).

I know how to do this using pinvoke for native libraries if I know what dll/function I want to call at compile time, but I can't find any information on how to do this at runtime.

Essentially what I'd like to do is call a method:

```
int result = ExecuteNativeFunction("someLibrary.dll", "foo");
```

and have it do something equivalent to:

```
[DllImport("someLibrary.dll")]
static extern int foo();

...

int result = foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would [this](http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/eng/samples/dotnet_dynpinvoke.asp) be what you are looking for? Using [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx), you can dynamically compile code that defines a new PInvoke method. See the class `DllRegServer` in the [linked file](http://www.msjogren.net/dotnet/download.asp?dynpinvoke.zip) for details.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for, though I was hoping I could avoid Reflection.Emit.